# joomla 3.1 how to route menu item alias

Tags: menuitem, joomla3.0

Usin joomla 3.1 with SEF and mod rewrite.
How can I get the link of the menu item that a "menu item alias" references ?
Using the code below renders the alias field of the menu items alias and not the "menu alias" destination.

```
 $menu->getItem($men->id)->route
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be the best approach but you could load this from the database, for example...

```
$menuLink=""; //to be used to store the result of our query
$alias='somealias'; //I am guessing you will already have the alias ready from some source

//query the database to find the link corresponding to this alias
$db=JFactory::getDbo();
$query=$db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('link');
$query->from('#__menu');
$query->where("alias='" . $alias . "'");
$db->setQuery($query);
try
{
    $result=$db->loadObject();
    $menuLink=$result->link;
}
catch(RuntimeException $e)
{
    JError::raiseError(500, $e->getMessage());
}
```

If someone comes up with a better way then that would also be good :) This is how I usually do it though, it works fine for me.  Hope this helps.